# FFmpeg - How to restream without delay and with metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I am using FFmpeg 5.0 (from command). How to restream: from sources of type (inputs): UDP/ RTSP/ HLS/ RTMP to RTMP output (on Nginx Server) (without delay, but contain metadata and service_name, as when I open the rtmp source in VLC player or other type of player, it shows service_name and other metadata, and stream in different formats (h264, mpeg2video). Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's ok? Or now edit? I use translator Google. Sorry!